# Angular 7 error when doing new app, Error: Cannot find module 'temp',

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular7

When I tried to do a new app using:

```
ng new first-app
```

The following error appears:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'temp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:587:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:513:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Junior\Documents\GitHub\angular-cli\lib\bootstrap-local.js:14:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
```

I tried to download the last node.js and the last npm version, also tried to get the last angular cli version but it is giving the same error.

I'm using Windows and I'm placing the app in a desktop folder call Angular.

Cli version command using ng -v:

[Cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ44a.png)

---

## Solved

What I did to solve the issue was to run the Node js using the Node.js command prompt that is located in the Node js in the window start menu and also I switched my window user to admin from the cmd using:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

[See the Node.js command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbjEU.png)

Comment: please mention node and angular cli version here

Comment: node : v11.0.0,  when I try to get the cli version using ng --version this error is return Error: Cannot find module 'temp' , I installed the cli to the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these steps

1. Uninstall @angular/cli `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. Clear npm cache `npm cache clean --force`
3. Install @angular/cli `npm i -g @angular/cli`

This is the issue with current node.
Try to install temp module by `npm i -g temp` and then run the `ng new first-app`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried those steps and is showing the same error.

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of cli running `ng -v` or in Angular 7 by `ng --version`

Comment: I added the screenshot to the post

Comment: I enter the command and is returning the same error, I'm using the CMD in administrador mode and is the same issue.... Thank you for taking the time to help me in this problem!

Comment: Try downgrading Node to 10.13.0

Comment: I did it and is the same issue :(

Comment: Hello! Now the problem is fixed!! I installed the node 11 again and then executed the Node.js command prompt that is located in the Node.js folder. One curious thing to notice is that the only different thing that I did was to start using the Node.js command prompt from the beggining and not first use the cmd...

Answer (score 1):

Try this to add the missing temp module entry:

```
npm i --save temp
```

if you have the problem with typescript (or something else) too, use following line:

```
npm i --save-dev typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved.

What I did to solve the issue was to run the Node js using the Node.js command prompt that is located in the Node js in the window start menu and also I switched my window user to admin from the cmd using:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```